# How can I format external hard disk that is not initialized and only detected in disk management?

Tags: external-hard-drive

My external hard disk has got some problem with GPT/MBR initialization. This says "The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error". No problem. Let it go.
Is there any way to format and make it usable?

Comment: If you cannot format it, it is likely dead.

Comment: Is it online / offline? The error in the description is what you get when you try to initialise?

Comment: You cannot format an uninitialized drive, as there's no partition table [MBR or GPT] on the drive, and therefore no existing partitions to format.  You either have a bad eSATA/USB cable, external case, or drive (troubleshooting in that order, or as @Smock mentioned, it may be offline).  Accessing the drive's S.M.A.R.T data will tell you if the drive itself is bad (`smartctl -a /dev/<drive>` and a long test should be ran: `smartctl -t long /dev/<drive>`)